# как передать значение data-id в value?

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<div class="book col">
<input type="radio" name="chosen" data-id="'.$xxx['xxx_id'].'" checked="checked">
</div>'
```

как передать значение data-id в value?

```
form action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="one" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: что вы хотите получить в итоге? Постарайтесь описать вашу проблему более развёрнуто

Comment: @Blacknife data-id="'.$xxx['xxx_id'].'" тут я из базы беру значение, а оно зависит от других показателей, поэтому в value я не могу передать что-то конкретное. должно передастся значение из data-id, дальше это отправляется на другую страницу через submit

Comment: `data-id="'.$xxx['xxx_id'].'"` как это вы так выводите значение? Почему не так `data-id="<?php echo $xxx['xxx_id']; ?>"`? Или вы весь `div` выводите через `echo`? Инпут один или их несколько? Из вопроса непонятно, почему вам нельзя сделать так: `<input type="hidden" name="one" value="<?php echo $xxx['xxx_id']; ?>">`

Comment: @Blacknife да,весь div находится в echo. количество инпутов зависит от значений в базе, которые определяются до этого. последнее Ваше предложение : даже так пытался, но не получается. да и к тому же мне нужно просто присвоить value значение data-id

Comment: а почему нельзя эти инпуты вставить в форму, чтобы браузер сам отправлял значение выбранного инпута, зачем этот огород?

Answer (score 1):

С эмулируем ситуацию, и как то так:

```
<div class="book col">
    <input type="radio" id="myVisibleInput" name="chosen" data-id="789873" checked="checked">
</div>

<form id="myForm" action="">
    <input type="hidden" id="myHiddenInput" name="one" value="">
</form>

<script>
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
    $('#myHiddenInput').val( $(myVisibleInput).data('id') );
});
</script>
```

*Надеюсь, с jQuery подойдет*